# Вывод представлений в ListView Xamarin.forms

Tags: xaml, mvvm, xamarin

Необходимо вывести представления в listView. На WPF сделал так:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CommissionVMs}" BorderBrush="White">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <views:Commission/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

где CommissionVMs - это коллекция viewModel для моих представлений, а Commission - непосредственно представление. Как мне это повторить на xamarin.forms?

Answer (score 0):

Всё, решил вопрос. Все дело в том, что надо было создать вьюху, которую хочу отображать в listView, как ViewCell, а не ContentPage и т.д. И теперь нормально отображает.